# Globalizing all common variables in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have some common variable in my Laravel project. For example, Logo, ico, title etc. will be displayed from their respective models. Now, the problem is, I need to declare all of the variables in every controllers index method, otherwise system is saying variable is undefined. How can I make these variables global?

Comment: may be in that case you can declare your all variables into Controller.php file's constructor. Then when you extends that class all variable default accessible into your child controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [view composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#view-composers) or [share data with all views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#passing-data-to-views) - it's right in the docs.

A simple example of using a view composer to share a variable with all views would be to use the wildcard (`*`) operator. Remember, you'll want to register all of this in one of your service providers.

```php
use App\Logo;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

View::composer('*', function ($view) {
    $view->with('logo', Logo::first());
});
```

The benefits of this approach is lets you organise everything you consider to be global in a single callback - but also it gives you the constraint to restrict it to certain views/partials.

Otherwise, more simply you can just use the `share` method.

```php
View::share('logo', Logo::first());
```